# Preventing duplicate entried in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (.cshrc and .sh scripts)

Tags: environment-variables

I'm using Scientific Linux 7. My shell is /bin/csh.

In my .cshrc, I set PATH preventing duplicates through `set -f path= ( "/new_entry/bin" $path:q )` according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77666/202228. This works perfectly, even if I source my `.cshrc` file amny time, there is no duplicated entries in `$PATH` variable.

I want the same behaviour for my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

In `.cshrc`, I tried to replace my old `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH globalentry:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by `set -f LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ( "globalentry" $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:q )` but then `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows `globalentry /usr/lib:/opt/intel/compiler70/ia32/lib:/opt/absoft/lib`, so looks like it used space   rather than `:` delimiter and the variable seemes to be messed up.

Is there a way ot prevent duplicates in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as it works for `PATH`?